# How to get host id with host's name? Zabbix

Tags: python, api, zabbix

Have hosts' names and whant to get their ids using names. Have list with hosts' names. Try

```
for host in list_regexed_hosts_names:
   ids = z.do_request(method="host.get", params={
            "output": ["hostid"],
            "filter": {
                "host": host
            }
        })
```

But id does not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request method seems incorrect as per Python [zabbix api](https://github.com/adubkov/py-zabbix/blob/master/README.rst) and host is expecting an array. So instead of looping each host you can directly give it as array. You can look at the zabbix [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/api/reference/host/get) for more details

Assuming list_regexed_hosts_names is an array or a list containing hostnames.

```
ids = z.do_request('host.get',
                   { 
                   'output' : ['hostid'],
                   'filter' :  { 'host': list_regexed_hosts_names}
                   }
      )
```